# Unable to transform string to datetime/timestamp in specific format in ADF dataflow

Tags: datetime-format, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

Trying to convert string value(2022-07-24T07:04:27.5765591Z) into datetime/timestamp to insert into SQL table in datetime format without losing any value till milliseconds. String which I am providing is actually a datetime and my source is ADLS CSV. I tried below options in data flow.

1. **Using Projection**-> Changed the datatype format for specific column into timestamp and format type-yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' however getting NULL in output.
   [image]
2. **Derived column**-> Tried below expressions but getting NULL value in output

toTimestamp(DataLakeModified_DateTime,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s%z')
toTimestamp(DataLakeModified_DateTime,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffK')
toTimestamp(DataLakeModified_DateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
[image]

I want the same value in output-

2022-07-24T07:04:27.5765591Z (coming as string) to 2022-07-24T07:04:27.5765591Z (in datetime format which will be accepted by SQL database)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to repro the issue and it is also giving me the same error, i.e., null values for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` timestamp format. The issue is with the string format you are providing in source. The ADF isn’t taking the given string as timestamp and hence giving NULL in return.

But if you tried with some different format, like keeping only 3 digits before `Z` in last format, it will convert it into timestamp and will not return NULL.

This is what I have tried. I have kept one timestamp as per your given data and other with some modification. Refer below image.

[image]

This will return NULL for the first time and datetime for second time.

[image]

But the format you are looking for is still missing. With the existing source format, the `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` would work fine. This format also works fine in SQL tables. I have tried and it’s working fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @UtkarshPal-MT-  Thanks for trying but I don't want to lose fraction of seconds digit.

Comment: But in this case first I will have to use substring to take data till three digit of milliseconds, right? or any other way to read the string value till 3 digits of milliseconds including Z like 2022-07-24T07:04:27.576Z

Comment: it's better if you iterate over each value in time column and transform the value to only get the 3 digits millisecond and then use timestamp function over it. This should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use to String instead of timestamp and use this to create your Desired timestamp

toString(DataLakeModified_DateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS')

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: Thanks for response but I am looking in this format- 2022-07-24T07:04:27.5765591Z in datetime/timestamp format so that I can save it into SQL.

Comment: In Mapping Data flow you have to excape the T And Z and expect that everything will be the same you are not missing anything